# Difficulty installing gcc 7.3.1

Tags: gcc, compiler

I'm currently having some issues, trying to install the 7.3.1 gcc version. (I need this version for a specific gpu setup)

I have added jonathonf's repository:

```
add-apt repository ppa:jonathonf/gcc-7.3

sudo apt update
```

However, when I try to install the package itself:

```
sudo apt install gcc-7.3.1
sudo apt install gcc-7.3
```

I receive following error:

```
E: Unable to locate package gcc-7.3.1
E: Unable to locate package gcc-7.3
```

EDIT:
output of apt policy gcc-7:

```
gcc-7:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 7.4.0-9ubuntu1~18.04.york0
  Version table:
     7.4.0-9ubuntu1~18.04.york0 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/gcc/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
     7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1 500
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
     7.3.0-30ubuntu1~18.04.york0 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/gcc-7.3/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
     7.3.0-16ubuntu3 500
        500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at [the packages published in the PPA](https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/gcc-7.3/+packages), you need to install `gcc-7`:

```
sudo apt install gcc-7
```

But since you have multiple versions of `gcc-7` available, including newer ones than 7.3, you also need to specify the version you want:

```
sudo apt install gcc-7=7.3.0-30ubuntu1~18.04.york0
```

This won’t get you 7.3.1 however.

Once that’s installed, you’ll need to put a hold on all the relevant packages so they don’t get upgraded:

```
sudo apt-mark hold gcc-7 ...
```

(I’m assuming your first command was copied incorrectly, it should have been `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/gcc-7.3`.)

Comment: This just installs gcc-7.4. I have checked my apt sources and the repository for jonathan is correctly added:  ```500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/gcc-7.3/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=LP-PPA-jonathonf-gcc-7.3,a=bionic,n=bionic,l=GCC 7.3,c=main,b=i386
     origin ppa.launchpad.net```

Comment: That means you’ve got something else also providing `gcc-7`. Could you [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/565074/edit) to show the output of `apt policy gcc-7`?

Comment: You are correct, there are indeed different versions of gcc-7. How could I remove them safely?

Comment: You can choose a specific version to install, see my update.

Comment: I receive dependency's errors, requires to install gcc-7.4. The following packages have unmet dependencies:
```gcc-7 : Depends: cpp-7 (= 7.3.0-30ubuntu1~18.04.york0) but 7.4.0-9ubuntu1~18.04.york0 is to be installed
         Depends: gcc-7-base (= 7.3.0-30ubuntu1~18.04.york0) but 7.4.0-9ubuntu1~18.04.york0 is to be installed
         Depends: libgcc-7-dev (= 7.3.0-30ubuntu1~18.04.york0) but 7.4.0-9ubuntu1~18.04.york0 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.``` On various platforms I've read that there is an issue with the 7.3 repo itself...