# Ubuntu 20.04 install gcc-7.3.1

Tags: ubuntu, gcc

How can I install **gcc-7.3.1** in **Ubuntu 20.04**. So far I could only find out the following solutions but they're for **Ubuntu 16.04** and **Ubuntu 18.04**.

1. [How can I install gcc 7.3 for ubuntu 16.04?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48846467/how-can-i-install-gcc-7-3-for-ubuntu-16-04)
2. [Difficulty installing gcc 7.3.1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/565074/difficulty-installing-gcc-7-3-1)

Also, I could not find a **gcc-7.3.1** version for **Ubuntu 20.04** here in this archive [Jonathon F](https://launchpad.net/%7Ejonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/gcc), it seems to only support **gcc** packages for **Ubuntu** lower than **20.04**.

I also found this [page](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/gcc) but I can't see **gcc-7.3.1**.

Please provide a solution. Thanks!

Comment: Enable **universe** `sudo add-apt-repository universe` ..... and `sudo apt install g++-7` provides gcc version 7.5.0 : Which is a bug fix version of previous gcc - 7.x versions https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/buglist.cgi?bug_status=RESOLVED&resolution=FIXED&target_milestone=7.5

Comment: @KnudLarsen I have __gcc-7.5.0__ version installed but will it help in building __tensorflow__ from source as they have only tested it in __gcc-7.3.1__ [see](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#linux) and I'm having some hard time with the build without __gcc-7.3.1__

Comment: @Ayush um, these are just arbitrary tested versions. Tensorflow is directly available for ubuntu 20.04, so a) no need, nor any advantage, to compile it yourself, b) You can use a modern compiler to build it. So, what is the problem you're **actually** solving by trying to install GCC 7.3.1?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I don't know see this [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/52650)

Comment: OK, a) why are you building from source at all b) the problem is that numpy expects a CPython-internal type that your Python doesn't supply, so the choice of compiler doesn't really matter c) you should probably tell the people in that issue that on Ubuntu 20.04, there's no tested compiler available, and you're just going to do it with the stock compiler.

Comment: @MarcusMüller So direct installation is the only solution...?

Comment: no, but it sounds a lot like it's the sensible solution for you.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Okay, Thanks!